# start a bat file from dotnet containing a curl request

Tags: c#, curl

this is the contents of a bat file, it just work fine if called in command prompt window on w10.

```
C:\temp\curl\curl-7.52.1-win32-mingw\curl-7.52.1-win32-mingw\bin\curl.exe "https://www.google.it/search?q=some+word+to+search" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br" -H "accept-language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1" -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" -H "x-chrome-uma-enabled: 1" -H "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "cache-control: max-age=0" -H "avail-dictionary: fmyVnlmA" -H "authority: www.google.it" -H "cookie: SID=CwTQtVs4fYt7DB3Dab_RV-CCb1MW_MoS4VqI1Quc5QInjio_9oaCtPX7Urm1H8plNmxthw.; HSID=AEuEIAvmo0gkQb0oT; SSID=AwN8NmVpx07HoQN9U; APISID=Lq3KiU9ffF2sSMDj/A89BR9KDMqlIjifZn; SAPISID=Fuv16j3VfLymbSNt/AgtVQZanYauCV_gEA; CONSENT=YES+IT.it+V8; OGPC=787587072-4:732465152-1:; NID=95=EgcASSzyHBsH2WmudwsVB3jvXegE3lhHs8Y6cF75ypHCL1pXTL_ZJET5yGIZEY6W64Lhh9k66dCkU5-dVKp3g4AOYSTYvg02bV9v_Xj0W9T7MyJEqFhqt9L3Y_S5wor6ClwWbfcC05SipOYulgpS4MoYYoO3zBc5CINq_cy6bpCHS-3ti1Um87bPQwjLZKQJTOm2PMpvzfLBWGbKnC4WjUo9kzjRYv7vUdyUN_2FiA; DV=oh8FotuvYScXBMhGFNhXdO3l9-t4swI" -H "x-client-data: CIW2yQEIo7bJAQjEtskBCKuKygEI+5zKAQipncoB" --compressed --proxy http://proxyserver:8080
```

calling from DotNet it does not start, this the code:

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName= @"C:\temp\curl\call.bat";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    using (StreamReader reader = p.StandardOutput)
    {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(result);
    }

}
```

[image: console]

Comment: what is the error when starting from C#?

Comment: If you run `call.bat` from the command line normally, I assume it works properly?

Comment: no errors running on c# it hangs on in p.WaitForExit(); running bat file in command prompt it works properly

Comment: changed to this it is working properly.  var process = new Process();
            var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\temp\curl\call-np.bat");
            startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo = startinfo;
            process.OutputDataReceived += (s, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args.Data); // do whatever processing you need to do in this handler
            };
            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();